# Does a convergent sequence in theory ever reach its limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Completing a question on the sequence $\{a_n\} = \frac n{2n+1}$. Does $a_n$ in this sequence ever actually get to $\frac12$ officially?

Comment: How is 'reach' defined

Comment: Actually get = to 1/2

Comment: $\frac n{2n+1}=\frac 12\implies 2n=2n+1\implies 0=1$.

Comment: Do the math:  does an index $n$ exist for which $\frac{n}{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Subnadeep Dey is there a condition which is the opposite to asymptotic? So another sequence that converges but is not asymptotic

Comment: To actually _reach_ the limit, one must often speed up toward the end. That's what Achilles did in real life in order to catch the tortoise. (And, in several regards, I'm not just kidding around here...)

Answer (score 8):

The sequence in your example will never 'reach' $1/2$ in the sense that
$$\forall\,n \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{n}{2n+1} \ne \frac{1}{2}$$
The fact that we still call $1/2$ the limit of the sequence expresses that we can get $n/(2n+1)$ arbitrary close to $1/2$ (*"as close as we want"*), we just have to take $n$ sufficiently large.

This doesn't mean that a sequence never reaches its limit; e.g.
$$1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots \to 1$$
This sequence converges to $1$ and reaches it (trivially, everywhere). This shows that it's a bad way to think about limits as *"where the sequence gets arbitrarily close to, but never reaches"*.

---

Another example, the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ with
$$a_n = \cases{ 1 & $n=2k+1$ $\quad$ odd \\ 1-10^{-k} & $n=2k$ $\quad\quad\;\;$ even}$$
you get
$$1 \,,\, 0.9 \,,\, 1 \,,\, 0.99 \,,\, 1 \,,\, 0.999 \,,\, \ldots$$
A sequence that converges to $1$ where infinitely many terms are equal to its limit $1$, but also infinitely many terms differ from its limit $1$.